# web.config gets modified when published

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, web-config, publish

I have an asp.net web application and everything is working correctly. Now I wanted to upload another app on a subdomain of my server and to run both I have to change hostingModel from "inprocess" to "outofprocess".
So I modified my web.config to

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AmsWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>

<!--ProjectGuid: XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-->
```

I found out that when I publish my application the original web.config file from the bin\Release\net6.0 folder gets deleted and a new and different one is appearing in the obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\Out folder looking like that

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AmsWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Why is this happening and what do I have to do to avoid this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got some feedback from my server host telling me to update the .csproj file with following addon

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

and now all is working as supposed.